# How to Bind Event with OOP JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to bind a Blur event into a Method with JS, and retrieve the object data. That's what I got:

```
class TestClass {
    constructor(input) {
        this.inputTest = input;

        this.objectTest = {
            1: "one",
            2: "two",
            3: "three"
        }

        this.isBinded = false;
    }

    test() {
        if(!this.isBinded) {
            this.inputTest.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
                alert("Test Event");

                // I need to access to Object Scope, but seems not to be working
                console.log(this.objectTest);
            });
        }

        this.isBinded = true;
    }
}

var test = new TestClass(document.querySelector("input"));
test.test();
```

So, this is a simple example of what I need. I have one input, and when I initialize the class, I bind a `blur` event. When I try it, it just shows me the alert, so apparently looks to work.

However, it seems it cannot access into the object scope, because it doesn't return me the `this.objectTest` object example from the object scope.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: `.bind(this)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind Or use an arrow function, which will take the scope of the method it was created in.

Comment: this inside the event handler is not the instance of your class, but the event object.

Comment: @Programmer: It's actually the DOM Element the handler is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using a regular function in the addEventListener it is rebinding this to the inputTest element. You need to use an arrow function to keep this as your class object. Like this:

```
this.inputTest.addEventListener("blur", ( event ) => {
            alert("Test Event");

            // I need to access to Object Scope, but seems not to be working
            console.log(this.objectTest);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, it seems it cannot access into the object scope, because it doesn't return me the this.objectTest object example from the object scope

Yes, indeed inside the `addEventListener` callback, `this` refers to the `input` that you are attaching the event to, so `this.objectTest` will be `undefined`, as it's not referring your class's `objectTest` property.

What you need to do is to make a reference to your class `this`, so you can access it inside the callback, you can assign it to another variable like this:

```
test() {
 var _self = this;
    if(!this.isBinded) {
        this.inputTest.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
            alert("Test Event");

            // I need to access to Object Scope, but seems not to be working
            console.log(_self.objectTest);
        });
    }

    this.isBinded = true;
}
```

**Demo:**

Here's a Demo showing how it works.

```js
class TestClass {
  constructor(input) {
    this.inputTest = input;

    this.objectTest = {
      1: "one",
      2: "two",
      3: "three"
    }

    this.isBinded = false;
  }



  test() {
    var _self = this;
    if (!this.isBinded) {
      this.inputTest.addEventListener("blur", function(event) {
        alert("Test Event");

        // I need to access to Object Scope, but seems not to be working
        console.log(_self.objectTest);
      });
    }

    this.isBinded = true;
  }
}

var test = new TestClass(document.getElementById("js-test"));
test.test();
```

```html
Check it : <input id="js-test" />
```